# I want to replace the data in a text file with an array and store it in a variable

Tags: c#, arrays, text

The goal is to graph the data in a text file.

I will store it as an `int` in the array `y` and as a `string` in the array `x`

There are two text files, `x.txt` and `y.txt`, each of which is separated by *spaces*. like `y` is `1 2 3 4 5 6`  and `x` is `a b c d`.

I hope to store it in array, like

```
 int[]    y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
 string[] x = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
```

I try `StreamReader`... but I'm fail

so I want to give an example of my problem.

```
StreamReader sy = new StreamReader("F:/C#/graph/graph/bin/Debug/y.txt", 
Encoding.Default);
        string[] ty = sy.ReadToEnd().Split(' ');
        Console.WriteLine(ty);
        for (int i = 0; i < ty.Length; i++)
        {
                y[i] = Int32.Parse(ty[i]);
                return;
                           }
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description we can help you with. What did you expect and what did happen? Please [edit] that into your question along with the exact text of error messages (if any)

Comment: One immediate problem: that `return` will exit your loop (and the method) at the first iteration. The rest is skipped. Remove it and try again

Comment: *I'm fail* is not s useful problem description. In what **specific way** does the code you've posted not work? When you step through the code (especially the `for` loop) in the  debugger, what does the behavior of the code tell you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
   using(System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("F:/C#/graph/graph/bin/Debug/x.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] x = line.Split(' ');
        }
    }

   using(System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("F:/C#/graph/graph/bin/Debug/y.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] yString = line.Split(' ');
        }
        int[] y = Array.ConvertAll(yString , s => int.Parse(s));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you leave the loop *prematurely*:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < ty.Length; i++)
  {
      y[i] = Int32.Parse(ty[i]);
      return; // <- Only 1st value will be read
  }
```

When querying data (e.g. file) we often use *Linq*; `StreamReader` is an overshoot (put a simple `File.ReadAllText`) if you all we want is to read the entire file:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  int[] y = File
    .ReadAllText(@"F:/C#/graph/graph/bin/Debug/y.txt")
    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
    .ToArray();

  string[] x = File
    .ReadAllText(@"F:/C#/graph/graph/bin/Debug/x.txt")
    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToArray();
```